# How can we export the data structre with seleted data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin

I am working on the PostgreSQL 9.1.4, I have to export the Data structure with 1 row data.

But PostgreSql have options of  "Data only or Structure only or Structure and data".

But my aim is to export the "**Datastructre with 1 row data**"  .

How can achieve this in PostgeSQL9.1.4?

Comment: Are you saying your table has multiple rows of data and you only want to export one of those rows?

Comment: That's a bizarre requirement, and not easily satisifed due to referential integrity requirements, etc. I'd probably do an SQL format schema-and-data dump then hand-edit out most of the data from the dump text.

Comment: Thank you, I wish to export the default entry which id is -1.

Comment: Yes, I have to export the single row with Data Structure.